# How to transform the given function to be defined in another range?

Tags: calculus, matlab, image-processing

I have the following weighting function:
$$  w(\rho) = k \cdot(\rho^\alpha)\cdot(1-\rho)^\beta,$$
where $\rho$ represents a pixel value expressed as a `double`, *i.e.*, it ranges from $0$ to $1$, and $ 1\le \alpha \le \beta$.

How can I convert this function so that it shows a curve similar to the given one but works for pixel values expressed as `uint8`, *i.e.*, ranging from $0$ to $255$?

In the following example of the function I take values $\alpha = 1$; $\beta =6$ and $k =17.6$.

[[image: plot for <span class=]$w(\rho) $ for $0\le \rho \le 1 $">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Bl5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to divide your uint8  values by $255$ as a float.  That gives you a value in $[0,1]$  That is almost certainly good enough for this purpose.

The subtlety comes because the float values may be equally distributed on $[0,1]$.  The inverse transformation would be to multiply the floats by $255$.  Since the float will never be $1$ you would never get a result of $255$.  Even if you round, $0$ and $255$ will only get hit half as often as the other values.  The improvement would be to multiply by $256$ and round down.  Now if the floats are equally distributed, so are the uint8s.  For the uint8 to float you could then divide by $256$.

Comment: thanks sir, I have done the same earlier and I got zeros instead of ones during conversion of float to uint8 for the values like this (6.376246841303954e-14) and so I incremented every value by one . I know its a dumb question to ask but , I wanted to know that ,given x < P < y ranges for a variable P in function and to use it for another range x1 < P < y1 ,doing a proportional conversion just like we did earlier is fine right.

Comment: @MOHANTEJA I don't understand: for me it seems correct that a pixel value expressed as `double` is $6.376246841303954\cdot e^{-14}$ and expressed as `uint8` is $0$. All `double`s between $0$ and $1/256$ should be mapped to $0$ when expressed as `uint8`.

Comment: @MOHANTEJA:  I am surprised that you can get a value of $6.37E-14$.  That is extremely small.  Most pixel values have only 16 or 24 bits, but this needs 44 to represent it.  I suspect you are not interpreting the input correctly.  If it is a correct input, it should be mapped to 0, as should any value less than $1/256$

Comment: @RossMillikan I using the weight function in denominator of a division.so I had to make zeros to ones in order to prevent division by zero, sorry I didn't mentioned that in the earlier comment.

Comment: [the matlab code I have used ](https://gist.github.com/mohanteja1/775aa179df41cac21a500ebc69e6aa14
)